# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 30, 3), found shape=(None, 26)

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a small problem with CNN. I want to use my CNN to predict L a b color values. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error. Since this is my first time working with a CNN, I have no idea what this error code means.

Here is the error code:

```
2023-05-30 16:57:03.347650: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\src\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\src\main.py", line 31, in main
    models.train.main(model='cnn', color='gray', type='sig', vis=False, explain=False,
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\src\models\train.py", line 571, in main
    train_cv(df, model, color, type, vis, explain, store_train, store_val, store_cv_model)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\src\models\train.py", line 314, in train_cv
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file2mx7mlql.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 295, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 30, 30, 3), found shape=(None, 26)
```

And this is my code:

```
elif algorithm == 'cnn':

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(30,30,3)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(3))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

I wanted to try an cnn model

Answer (score 0):

Working with TensorFlow, I have found that reading the error conveys most of the problem and its solution. Here you can see that the error is caused by a shape mismatch between the input shape expected by the model and the actual shape of the input data.

The model you defined expects input data of the form (None, 30, 30, 3). As such it expects a stack of images that are 30 pixels high and wide with 3 RGB color channels. However, the input data you provide is of the form (None, 26), which means that it does not have the required dimensions for processing by the convolution layer.

To solve this problem, make sure your input data has the correct shape (None, 30, 30, 3) before feeding it to the model. After that, they can be passed to the model without raising a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

The model expects an input shape of (30, 30, 3), but the data being fed into the model has a shape of (None, 26). Try modifying the input shape in your model to match your data. I.e. you should change the input shape in the model to (26, 26, 3) assuming that the data has 3 colour channels.

```py
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(26,26,3)))
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hello @AbdelRahman, thank you for your help ^^ Unfortunately, I am encountering this error:

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 26)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential' (type Sequential):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 26), dtype=float64)
• training=True
• mask=None

Additional information that I forgot to mention: My training data has the shape (1343, 26).

Comment: Interesting. The model expects a 4-dimensional input but your input data has only 2 dimensions. Well, at least according to the mess that got created with my code. I'll look into it.

Comment: @TorstenBuchert To troubleshoot, let's first try and set the batch size manually and see if that's the issue.
`model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1343, 26, 26, 3)))`

If it doesn't work, we'll try resizing the dataset within the program to see if the code is fundamentally even functional. (It should be, but just in case)

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer 'max_pooling2d' is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 1343, 24, 24, 32)
I don't understand why the expected ndim is four while I only have a 2-dimensional dataset.thank you for helping me until now :)

Comment: @TorstenBuchert OH. I am pretty sure the problem lies in the dataset size then. Do you have discord? I think we should take this into a discord chat/call instead of the SO forum.
Also, sorry for making this drag for this long; I am not an expert yet.

EDIT: There